# WebSockets - Switch between ws/wss after connection?

Tags: node.js, websocket

Is it possible to first establish a ws:// connection (not SSL encrypted) and then after communicating a bit switch to wss:// ond the same connection (and vice versa)?

Since WebSockets are long living connections, it seems to make sense to me. And I really would need it in one of my projects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't switch from unencrypted (ws) to encrypted (wss) in the same socket connection. You could establish two connections from the start and just not use the encrypted one until you are ready if you are concerned about setup latency. Otherwise, just create a new encrypted session when you are ready.

Comment: Yep, there are some protocols/libraries that support midstream wrapping of an unencrypted connection with an encrypted stream but WebSockets is not one of them. On the other hand, if you are willing to take a performance hit, you could do the encryption/decryption in directly in Javascript over an unencrypted WebSocket connection. The Forge library is a TLS (SSL) library for Javascript: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge